# Make windows XP ask for password

Tags: passwords, windows-xp-embedded

We have software that have some features that are so sensitive that we want to verify the identity of the user. Instead of using a own user/password scheme we would really like to either test the password against the user password in XP, or even make Windows self reauthenticate the user so we can make sure that it is an authorized person that accesses the function.

Or software is only running on windows XP embedded.

I do not know if this is possible at all, does windows have any such features?

Comment: Is this software created by your or your business or is this third party software that you do not have the source code for?

Comment: This is software created by our business.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Ask for the user's password using [`CredUIPromptForCredentials()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177%28VS.85%29.aspx) (works for any username/password, not just Windows logon)
- Validate it using either [`LogonUserEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378189%28VS.85%29.aspx)...
- ...or SSPI: KB180548: [How to validate user credentials on Microsoft operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180548)
- ...or even your own mechanism.
- The `Cred*()` API allows credentials to be stored by Windows and encrypted using the logon password.

Comment: This is exactly the functionality I was looking for. I didn't know that Microsoft exposed that part of its api. Thank you very much.